# Check Whether A Boolean Formula Has One Satisfying Assignment

Tags: computer-science, np-complete

So I'm reviewing old homeworks for an upcoming comp sci test and I came across this question:

Say whether the following statement is True, False or Unknown:

> The problem of checking whether a given Boolean formula has exactly
>   one satisfying assignment, is NP-complete

My original answer to this was True because it seems to me that you can reduce SAT to this. Here's my solution:

Let's call this problem EX_SAT. Given a boolean formula s, we can construct a TM M where L(M) = SAT using EX_SAT. Assume that we have a NTM P that decides EX_SAT, and a NTM Q that decides DOUBLE_SAT (the problem of determining whether a Boolean formula has two or more satisfying assignments). We that DOUBLE_SAT is NP-complete because we reduced SAT to it in an earlier homework problem.

```
M = on input s
    1. Run P on s.
    2. If P accepts, then accept.
    3. If P rejects then run Q on s.
    4. If Q accepts then accept.
    5. If Q rejects then reject.
```

I see that EX_SAT doesn't have a polynomial time verifier, and I also see the one flaw in this proof is that I also have to use DOUBLE_SAT to complete it - which probably doesn't allow us to conclude that EX_SAT is NP-complete, but I thought I would ask this here because it might aid in my understanding of the topic.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is an open problem because I think that the problem of "does φ have exactly one satisfying assignment?" is, I believe, co-NP-complete by a reduction from the unsatisfiability problem, which is known to be co-NP-complete.  The idea is that given a formula φ with variables v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ..., v<sub>n</sub>, we can construct the formula φ' as

φ' = (φ ∨ w) ∧ (w → ¬ v<sub>1</sub>) ∧ (w → ¬ v<sub>2</sub>) ∧ ... ∧ (w → ¬ v<sub>n</sub>)

The idea behind φ' is that if φ is unsatisfiable, this has exactly one satisfying assignment: make the new variable w true and make each v<sub>i</sub> false.  Otherwise, for each satisfying assignment of φ, there is one satisfying assignment to φ' formed by using the satisfying assignment to φ with w set to false.  This reduction can be computed in polynomial-time, so the problem of "does φ have exactly one satisfying assignment?" is co-NP-hard.  Since it's also in co-NP (because you can easily verify a "no" answer given a certificate containing two satisfying assignments), this problem is NP-complete.  Since it's unknown whether NP = co-NP, no co-NP-complete problem is known to be in NP.  Thus it's an open problem whether this problem is also contained in NP, though I think the general conjecture is "no."

Hope this helps!

Comment: "because you can easily verify a "no" answer given a certificate containing two satisfying assignments" - what if the formula has no satisfying assignments?  I'm pretty sure that exactly-1-SAT is in $\Sigma_2^p\cap\Pi_2^p$, but not known to be lower.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that!  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

For the problem to be NP-complete it has to be in NP, which means it has to have a polynomial time verifier for all "yes" answers.  If the exactly-1-satisfying-assignment question is in NP, that means there must be "yes" answers and verifiers for the following two questions:

Does this formula have a satisfying assignment?
Does this formula have no more satisfying assignments?

There's a polynomial time verifier for the first question, but not the second unless NP = coNP.  Since the status of NP = coNP is unknown, the status of the main question also has to be "unknown."